# Tensor Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I want to multiply a 3d Tensor ($2\times 2\times 4$) with itself, and the result should be a tensor with the same shape. How does a multiplication like this works?

for an example take the shape that is formed from these four $2\times 2$ matrices:

$\begin{pmatrix} 
0.2 & 0.8 \\
0.4 & 0.6 
\end{pmatrix}$,
$\begin{pmatrix} 
0.2 & 0.8 \\
0.7 & 0.3 
\end{pmatrix}$,
$\begin{pmatrix} 
0.6 & 0.4 \\
0.4 & 0.6 
\end{pmatrix}$,
$\begin{pmatrix} 
0.6 & 0.4 \\
0.7 & 0.3 
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: That has only sixteen entries, how is it a cube? A $4\times 4\times 4$ cube should have 64 entries.

Comment: oops. sorry. I will edit the question. Tnx!